# Abort core dumped, haven't seen a fix for OCELOT users and I haven't found anything else online

Tags: c, ocelot

I have seen many fixes for this but none for the program I use (C language on OCELOT), can you please help me fix it?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    int opt;
    char name[] = "Franco";
    
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":if:lrx")) != -1)
    {
    switch(opt)
    {
    case 'f': ;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(optarg, "w+");
    fputs(name, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    break;
    
    default:
    abort();
    }
    }
    
    printf("Name: %s", name);
    }
```

Expected Output: Franco

Actual Output: Abort (core dumped)

For reference, this is the assignment

Write a program to write your first name (hard coded) to the screen and possibly to a file whose name is passed into the program from the command line. It can be written in upper or lower case or mixed case as the default.

Usage: writer [-f filename]

If the -f option is included with a filename, then create a file with that name or overwrite a previously existing file and write your name in on the first line.
If the -f option is not included, then only write your name to the screen followed by a newline.
Use a copy of the original getopt to parse the command line.

Be sure to test whether a file open succeeds or not and close any file you open when done.
any help is appreciated

Comment: You are _not_ checking `fopen` return value as per instructions

Comment: Also, how are you running the program? Are you sure it isn't hitting the explicit `abort();` that you have added to the code?